# Why authorize purchase api returning numericString xml field

Tags: authorize.net

i am sending purchase request in xml with createcustomer profile.

customerProfileId is returning good but customerpayment profile id is returning in field customerPaymentProfileIdList > numericString.

here is full response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<createTransactionResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
<messages>
    <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
    <message>
        <code>I00001</code>
        <text>Successful.</text>
    </message>
</messages>
<transactionResponse>
    <responseCode>1</responseCode>
    <authCode>R7BVRZ</authCode>
    <avsResultCode>Y</avsResultCode>
    <cvvResultCode>P</cvvResultCode>
    <cavvResultCode>2</cavvResultCode>
    <transId>60032752664</transId>
    <refTransID />
    <transHash>C1F3242645F7F118D709452E5758AF35</transHash>
    <testRequest>0</testRequest>
    <accountNumber>XXXX0015</accountNumber>
    <accountType>MasterCard</accountType>
    <messages>
        <message>
            <code>1</code>
            <description>This transaction has been approved.</description>
        </message>
    </messages>
    <transHashSha2 />
</transactionResponse>
<profileResponse>
    <messages>
        <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
        <message>
            <code>I00001</code>
            <text>Successful.</text>
        </message>
    </messages>
    <customerProfileId>1813409569</customerProfileId>
    <customerPaymentProfileIdList>
        <numericString>1808086931</numericString>
    </customerPaymentProfileIdList>
    <customerShippingAddressIdList />
</profileResponse>
</createTransactionResponse>
```

Comment: Are you asking *why* Authorize.Net does this? Shouldn't you be asking them?

Comment: it seem like this is some development issue i mean what is that tag mean numericString its not present in documentation

Comment: It's hardly a development issue. It's how it works in *production*.

Comment: so you mean to say that <customerPaymentProfileIdList>
        <numericString>1808086931</numericString>
    </customerPaymentProfileIdList> is normal , then why its defined differently in documentation.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/) defines this field as being present